# Combining Build triggers in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two build triggers (poll SCM and FStrigger-MonitorFiles) configured for a job, say the polling is scheduled for daily poll (@daily) , Now the build is triggered if poll SCM detects change or FStrigger-MonitorFiles does which is normal behavior.

But if both detects the change the build will be triggered twice as each triggers tries to trigger the build , how do i achieve combining the results of above two triggers daily and trigger/not trigger the build only once.

Comment: Interesting... I don't know of any way to ignore/disable a pending trigger on a job

Comment: Something similar already exists exists in BuildResultsTrirgger , like   one schedule and one trigger on multiple monitors, but you can only monitor jobs not any environment as such :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a special trigger job that is scheduled for both triggers.
Inside this job by using system groovy script you could check if any build of the target job has been built today. Then according to the results of the check this job does or does not trigger the target job.

Comment: Could you expand on that answer? I am having difficulties in understanding how a special trigger job can be scheduled for both triggers, without shifting the question from the original job to the trigger job.