# Call Poll SVN build trigger using Groovy Script in Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a ScriptTrigger scheduled for a job to run every 2 hours, now including some of the action from the scripts, i also want to look for any changes in SVN.

The easiest way using POLL SCM build trigger together with script trigger this works fine , but in each schedule if at all my script trigger wants to schedule a build and if my poll SCM also detect change there will be two builds done which is redundant.

To avoid this I need to write a groovy scrip to do the function poll SCM does on its schedule, **Can anybody help with groovy script to see if the are any changes in SCM (SVN)?**

Or is there any way to combine this triggers for single schedule and trigger, I already have this question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22348897/3109547) .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was going to point you to this question, until I realized it was you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348897/combining-build-triggers-in-jenkins

Comment: @Yup, i thought if at-least I get to know how to poll through script I can some what solve my other question you have mentioned that i had asked before :P

Comment: Try having a look at the source code of this plugin, it may give you what you need. [PollSCM](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PollSCM+Plugin)